# Pouchdb Angular2 webpack issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, karma-jasmine

I am unit-testing my Angular 2 provider using Jasmine 2.5, Webpack 2.2.1, and karma 1.3.0 ...

I have already use my provider within ionic project and build it with ionic app-scripts all works fine.

However when I tried to build it with angular webpack process something goes wrong

I use Pouchdb and its constructor is badly translated and an error happened.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: pouchdb_browser_1.default is not a constructor ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: pouchdb_browser_1.default is not a constructor

If I build it then change pouchdb_browser_1.default to pouchdb_browser using postbuild process code works fine.

Unfortunately I'm not able to change code that will be executed during test.

Please see below my **webpack.test.js**

```
const helpers = require('./helpers'),
webpack = require('webpack'),
LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin'); `module.exports = {

devtool: 'inline-source-map',



resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [helpers.root('src'), 'node_modules']
},

module: {
    rules: [{
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: [helpers.root('node_modules')]
    }, {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
            // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
            helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
            helpers.root('node_modules/@angular')
        ]
    }, {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        query: {
            // use inline sourcemaps for "karma-remap-coverage" reporter
            sourceMap: false,
            inlineSourceMap: true,
            module: "commonjs",
            removeComments: true
        },
        exclude: [/\.e2e\.ts$/]
    }, {
        enforce: 'post',
        test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
        loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
        include: helpers.root('src'),
        exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
    }],
},

plugins: [
    // fix the warning in ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('./src')
    ),

    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true,
        options: {

            /**
             * Static analysis linter for TypeScript advanced options configuration
             * Description: An extensible linter for the TypeScript language.
             *
             * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
             */
            tslint: {
                emitErrors: false,
                failOnHint: false,
                resourcePath: 'src'
            },

        }
    })
]};
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with transpilation of CommonJS to ES6 modules. Are you importing PouchDB the recommended TypeScript way, i.e. like this?

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```